# How to direct the RazorEditor in Visual Studio to pickup the script# mscorlib.dll instead of .Net Framework mscorlib.dll?

Tags: razor, script#

We are working on a Html templating engine using Razor syntax that converts the html template to scrip# code.

When we add a cshtml file in a ScriptSharp project, the intellisense provided by RazorEditor in visual studio is resolving the System, System.Collections namespaces and the types within those namespaces to .net Framework mscorlib.dll instead of ScriptSharp mscorlib.dll.
But the intellisense in the C# code editor correctly resolves the namespaces to Script# mscorlib, since the csproj file for the Script# project contains a ReferencePath to the folder containing the script# mscorlib.dll.

I have  tried the following ,but no luck

- Added a web.config file in the ScriptSharp project folder and
  explicitly added reference to ScriptSharp mscorlib dll
  insystem.web>compilation>assemblies section.
- Created a bin folder and copied the scriptsharp mscorlib dll.

Is there a way to hint the Razor editor to pick up the script# mscorlib.dll instead of
 .net Framework mscorlib.dll?

Answer (score 3):

Razor uses a special config section, something like this, it doesn't use the `compilation` element.

```
<system.web.webPages.razor>
  ...
  <pages pageBaseType="System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage">
    <assemblies>
      ...
    </assemblies>
    <namespaces>
      ...
    </namespaces>
  </pages>
</system.web.webPages.razor>
```

You will also need to add the definition of this config section:

```
<configSections>
  <sectionGroup name="system.web.webPages.razor" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorWebSectionGroup, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35">
    <section name="host" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.HostSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
    <section name="pages" type="System.Web.WebPages.Razor.Configuration.RazorPagesSection, System.Web.WebPages.Razor, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" requirePermission="false" />
  </sectionGroup>
</configSections>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply Paul. But If I try this I get this error "Unrecognized configuration section System.web.webPages.razor/assemblies."

Comment: I tried that already, but no luck. Looks like assemblies element is not valid under any of these elements System.web.webPages.razor, host, pages.

Comment: When it complains about System.web.webPages.razor make sure the System.Web.WebPages dll is referenced and is set to Copy Local: True